# Azure Table: Choose a partition key to efficiently sort records by time and user id

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm currently tracking API call metadata in an Azure Table with `PartitionKey` being `UserId` and `RowKey` being a random `Guid`. This helps me query records that belong to a specific user. However, I need to periodically migrate data to an analytics service to get information on how often an API is called, average response time, etc. I need to come up with a better `PartitionKey` strategy to do this.

These are the options I'm considering for `PartitionKey`:

1) *Round down current UTC time to the nearest minute and convert it to ticks.* This allows me to download data periodically using time intervals, but I can't efficiently look up data associated to a specific user.

2) *Use a synthetic key made up of {ticks}_{userId}.* Is it possible to execute a filtered query like `Where(m => m.PartitionKey.Contains(ticks))` or `Where(m => m.PartitionKey.Contains(userId))`? If so, is this a scalable approach?

3) *Save two records (one with ticks and another with userId being the partition key).*  If I go with this approach, how do I ensure that both records are saved all the time assuming there is no way to enforce an atomic transaction?

To me, the most important thing right now is to sort records by time. Thus, I'm mainly considering changing my logic to fit #1. However, I'd like to find out if I can efficiently query records both by time and user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Round down current UTC time to the nearest minute and convert it to
>   ticks. This allows me to download data periodically using time
>   intervals, but I can't efficiently look up data associated to a
>   specific user.

This approach would certainly work for fetching the API calls by date/time however if you need to fetch the data by user then this approach would fail miserably as full table scan needs to be performed.

> 2) Use a synthetic key made up of {ticks}_{userId}. Is it possible to
>   execute a filtered query like Where(m =>
>   m.PartitionKey.Contains(ticks)) or Where(m =>
>   m.PartitionKey.Contains(userId))? If so, is this a scalable approach?

Unfortunately this approach will not work because Azure Tables do not support `Contains` query. You can find the list of supported LINQ OData query operators here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service.

> 3) Save two records (one with ticks and another with userId being the
>   partition key). If I go with this approach, how do I ensure that both
>   records are saved all the time assuming there is no way to enforce an
>   atomic transaction?

This, by far, is the best approach. In this case you will store two records - one with partition key representing date/time stamp and other with user id as partition key. In fact, this is something I have used extensively in my projects.

Regarding your comment about atomic transactions, you are absolutely correct. Because you're using 2 separate partition keys, you can't use entity batch transactions.

What I have done is implemented an eventual consistency pattern in my application. When I receive a request, I simply save the request as a message in a storage queue. If I am able to write the message, then my entities will eventually be available in storage. Next I wrote a function which gets triggered whenever a message is saved in a queue. This function would read the message and then writes 2 separate entities using `InsertOrReplace` semantic to ensure that data eventually gets saved in table.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I can try the storage queue option as well. Do you have any examples showing how to trigger a function when a message arrives? I've never done anything like this before.

Comment: Also, regarding sort by time, is rounding down to the minute a good idea? Or should the precision be at the second level? Remember that this is saving each API request. Is it true that each partition is limited to 2K throughput per second?

Comment: Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp.

Comment: Regarding your question about rounding time to a minute, I think that's fine. It all depends on how many records are you expecting. If you go with a seconds precision, you will end up querying across partitions which is not a good design. Even Azure Diagnostics use minute level precision.